# Is there a way to limit the number of installs of an APK if it is emailed?

Tags: android, installation, apk

Hi I would like to send my android apk file to a limited number of users so that they can test it out on their phones. I know that if I email it to them then I have to rely that they dont share the apk or forward it.

Is there a way to limit the number of installs of an APK if I email it. One thought I had was to sign the apk with a very short expiration say like 1-2 days to give the users a chance to install it. That way if they forward the apk days/months later it will not install because of the epired signature. But then what does that mean with regards to my ownership of that apk since the signature is expired.

I would appreciate your feedback regarding this issue as I am a new developer and am just starting to understand the publishing process.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you own a domain and have hosting, then on the first run, you could upload data saying that there is a new install, and check if you have exceeded the maximum number of installs. I have no idea how you would implement it, but that is one possible solution.

Comment: thank you for he suggestion. Unfortunately, I do not have a domain to hos the app yet.

Comment: You could check out the Google Analytics SDK http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html#referrals It might let you track install count. I don't know much about it, but it might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Signing with an expiry date is a good solution to prevent it from being reused after some time. By default, Eclipse or IntelliJ sign with a debug key, so you don't have to worry about ownership. You can just use that one. To release the app on the android market, you need to sign it with expiry of 50 years.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I'm glad I'm not on the wrong track here. I guess it does not mater with regards to ownership of the apk if it is signed or not. Someone can modify the apk and resign it even if the original signature has not expired. It only matters to Android installing the apk. As for the debug key, I think that has a 1 year expiration, so I still need to make a short term signature keystroke. In anycase, I'm just trying to prevent erroneous installs by unknown people if the email is forwarded carelessly, before I post the app on android market.

Comment: Any app can be resigned and used like that. If you are really worried about the app being used even with wrong key, then you should consider adding code logic. A simple date check can go a long way.